# Generating new version of all.js to reflect changes from application.js: how does Rails 3.2.12 compile all.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

There are similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789233/rails-precompile-all-js-missing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425929/rails-3-1-strategy-for-pre-compiling-controller-specific-js-assets), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905117/my-application-js-wont-work-and-application-css-wont-update-in-rails), but none answer the question.

How does all.js get compiled in production for Rails 3.2.12? As illustrated below by the production.rb file, compiling assets is disabled so it's unclear how all.js gets generated in the first place.

Running `rake assets:precompile` generates the following error:

> rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile' (See
>   the list of available tasks with rake --tasks)

The root issue is how to update all.js to reflect the newest code in application.js. Restarting the server hasn't helped, so what triggers all.js to get recompiled?

```
Test::Application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

# The production environment is meant for finished, "live" apps.
# Code is not reloaded between requests
    config.cache_classes = true

    # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
    config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"

    # For nginx:
    # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

    # If you have no front-end server that supports something like X-Sendfile,
    # just comment this out and Rails will serve the files

    # See everything in the log (default is :info)
    # config.log_level = :debug

    # Use a different logger for distributed setups
    # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

    # Use a different cache store in production
    # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

    # Disable Rails's static asset server
    # In production, Apache or nginx will already do this
    config.serve_static_assets = false

    # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and javascripts from an asset server
    # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

    # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
    # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

    # Enable threaded mode
    # config.threadsafe!

    # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
    # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true

    # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

    # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
    config.assets.compress = true

    # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
    config.assets.compile = false

    # Generate digests for assets URLs
    config.assets.digest = true

    # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
    # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

    # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
    # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

    # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
    # config.force_ssl = true   
end
```

Comment: have you tried running `rake assets:precompile` task? I'm not 100% it was available with rails 3 though

Comment: @arieljuod yes it gives an error: `rake aborted!
     Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)`. any suggestions? thanks for your help!

Comment: According to the guide for version 3.2 it should work with that command https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: The simple solution would be to put this code `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['all.js']` inside `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally were able to refresh `all.js` with the newest changes from `application.js` using these (suboptimal) steps:

1. Discovered the installed Ruby was incompatible with Rails 3.2.12, so downgraded to Ruby 2.1.2. This fixed the `rake assets:precompile` error.
2. Ran the following commands, some of which are likely superfluous but there was no time to isolate the minimal number of steps needed:

   - `bundle exec rake assets:clean`
   - `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
   - `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
   - `rake assets:precompile --trace`
   - `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
   - `rm all.js`

The regenerated `all.js` magically appeared after the `rm all.js` step, but in case this doesn't work for others, please remember to back up `all.js` first!